# What could be causing the 'Unexpected token' error when rendering options from a categories map function in a React CRM project?

Tags: reactjs, crm

Hi friends facing this issue since 5 days not able to solve it can anyone help resolving it

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (211:16)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|       columnNumber: 13
|     }

> }, categories?.map(function (category, index) {
> |     return /*#**PURE***/React.createElement("option", {
> |       key: index,

tried reinstalling node modules asked chatgpt and Bard ai cannot resolve it